# Change Border Color of a JButton in Java Swing preserving the insets

Tags: java, swing, border, jbutton

I want to change the border color of a JButton component in Java Swing.

I have tried the following:

```java
package com.example.test;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    public Test() {

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton button1 = new JButton("Test Button 1");
        JButton button2 = new JButton("Test Button 2");
        button2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));

        panel.add(button1);
        panel.add(button2);

        this.add(panel);


        setSize(400, 400);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel( UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName() );
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        Test t = new Test();
    }
}
```

This generates two buttons, on button2 component I try to change border color but it removes the padding. Is there anyway to preserve the original insets of a standard JButton and just change the color?

Note: I assume that the insets are being removed when assigning the new Border. But I am not 100% sure about it.

[image: JButton Change Border Color]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of creating a `LineBorder`, use a `CompoundBorder`:

```
button2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(
            BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED, 1), 
            BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(
                button1.getBorder().getBorderInsets(button1).top, 
                button1.getBorder().getBorderInsets(button1).left, 
                button1.getBorder().getBorderInsets(button1).bottom, 
                button1.getBorder().getBorderInsets(button1).right)));
```

I took the `BorderInsets` for the `button1` so that both of them have the same size.

My answer is based on @MadProgrammer answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30239657/2180785)

[image]

---

Btw don't extend `JFrame`, create an instance of it instead and if you really need to extend a component, be it a `JPanel`: [Extends JFrame vs. creating it inside the program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22003802/extends-jframe-vs-creating-it-inside-the-program)

Also don't forget to call

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

On your `JFrame` instance, so that your program terminates when you close it.

And also you missed to place your program on the EDT, see more of this on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41559787/2180785)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the side comments/suggestions. It helps.